# Remove lines with specific pattern

Tags: unix, awk, lines, text-processing

I have a file with this specific format:

```
T   11722   A   330:0:0:0:0:0   315:0:0:0:0:0
T   11723   B   0:330:0:0:0:0   0:316:0:0:0:0
T   11725   C   0:327:0:0:0:0   0:314:0:0:0:0
T   11726   D   330:0:0:0:0:0   314:0:0:0:0:0
T   11727   E   0:6:0:323:0:0   0:6:0:309:0:0
T   11728   F   0:0:0:328:0:0   0:1:0:314:0:0
T   11729   G   0:325:0:0:0:0   0:315:0:0:0:0
```

I would like to remove any lines that don't have two values in columns 4 and 5.

For instance, if a line has the specific format:

```
T   11722   A   330:0:0:0:0:0   315:0:0:0:0:0
```

remove it.

If it has the following format (two values per column in columns 4 and 5):

```
T   11727   E   0:6:0:323:0:0   0:6:0:309:0:0
```

Keep it.

Thus, the expected result should be:

```
T   11727   E   0:6:0:323:0:0   0:6:0:309:0:0
T   11728   F   0:0:0:328:0:0   0:1:0:314:0:0
```

I have no idea how to set up something under unix but I am guessing there should be an easy way around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: What to do with line F?

Comment: according to your logic the expected result will contain only 2 lines, right?

Comment: @Pieter21, line F has two values in column 5, so I want to keep it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes, the expected result would only contain 2 lines. I will update my question with the expected result.

Comment: @AP38, I would also noted *two values per column in columns 4 **OR** 5*, but not **and**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to print lines where there's 2 or more non-zero values in $4 or $5? That'd be:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[1-9][0-9]*/,"&",$4)>1 || gsub(/[1-9][0-9]*/,"&",$5)>1' file
T 11727 E 0:6:0:323:0:0 0:6:0:309:0:0
T 11728 F 0:0:0:328:0:0 0:1:0:314:0:0
```

Comment: after the `gsub` expression, it should become, for example, `0:&:0:&:0:0`, and what the `>1` means here? can you help to explain it?

Comment: `&` is a backreference that means "the entire string that matched the regexp" just like in sed. `>1` means `greater than 1`. So gsub() will replace each matching string by itself and return a count of how many times it did that and if the count is greater than 1 then you found at least 2 non-zero numbers.

Comment: Ok, brilliant. The `&` in gsub is used to keep to matched pattern. And use the return value of gsub to distinguish the number of substitutions. Thanks for your explanations. :)

Comment: Thank you very much @EdMorton! This works just great!

Comment: @EdMorton, the only thing I would add to this approach is `OFS='\t'`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there's no hint in the question about needing tabs in the output. It actually looks to me like the input has 3 blank chars between fields so maybe `OFS='<blank><blank><blank>'` would be useful and actually if retaining the spacing is important it might be better to just do the gsub()s on tmp variables. In any case I expect the OP can massage to suit

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'function get_count(s, c, len) { 
         len=split(s,a,":"); while(len--) if(a[len]){ c++ } 
         return c 
     } BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }get_count($4) > 1 || get_count($5) > 1' file
```

---

- `function get_count(s, c, len) { ... }` - function returning the count of non-zero values in the given string
- `split(s,a,":")` - splitting the string `s` into array `a` by separator `:`
- `while(len--) if(a[len]){ c++ }` - accumulating non-zero count

The output:

```
T   11727   E   0:6:0:323:0:0   0:6:0:309:0:0
T   11728   F   0:0:0:328:0:0   0:1:0:314:0:0
```

Comment: There's a trick for making 'local' variables in an Awk function: name them as parameters to the function (but you don't need to supply values for them when you call it): `function get_count(s,      c, len) { … }`.  These are initialized to zero/empty when the function is called with a single argument, and are separate from variables with the same name outside the function.